# Showing computed percentage in chartist label

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

Below code renders charist charts with label and appropriate value
I want to append computed percentage to each lable
i.e

- One (5.55%)
- Two (16.66%)
- Three (27.77%)
- Four (50.00%)

```js
c_labels = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
c_series = [10, 30, 50, 90];
options = {}

new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart', {
  labels: c_labels,
  series: c_series,
}, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
```

Comment: What's your question again? Have you tried your code? Is the above code not working? If so, what errors/problem have you encountered?

Comment: cant you just use `c_series = [555, 1666, 2777, 5000]`? Or better yet, use `c_series = [5.55, 16.66, 27.77, 50]`.There is not enough information of what your question really is, so im assuming your problem is with math?

Comment: percentage shown is manual calculated.
i want to append the percentage values to label.

Comment: you mean, ***"calculated in the code"***, not ***"manually***.

Answer (score 2):

your code have many errors. Its needs to be correct as below

```js
var c_labels = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
var c_series = [5.55, 16.66, 27.77, 50];

var options = {
  width: 300,
  height: 200
};


new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
  labels: c_labels,
  series: [c_series]
}, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want to show the percentage in each labels. That only needs a simple string formatting, I pressume.

What you do is get the sum of your series using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). (*let's call it `total`*)

Next, for each item in your series, divide it by the `total` then multiply by 100. That way, you get the percentage of each series over the `total`:

```js
var c_labels = ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
  c_series = [10, 30, 50, 90],
  newLabels = [];
var total = c_series.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0);

for (var i = 0; i < c_series.length; i++) {
  var percentage = ((c_series[i] / total) * 100).toFixed(2),
    newLabel = c_labels[i] + '(' + percentage + '%)'; //simple string concatenation
  //assign the new string to our new labels
  newLabels[i] = newLabel;
}

new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
  labels: newLabels,
  series: [c_series] //YOUR SERIES SHOULD BE INSIDE AN ARRAY!
}, {
  stackBars: true,
  axisY: {
    labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
      return (value / 1000) + 'k';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
```

**Note:**
Using [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) automatically rounds off the number. You can remove it if you want but I added it so we can get 2 decimal precision. You can also try [`toPrecision`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision) or a [combination](http://www.saintsatplay.com/blog/2014/08/handling-floating-point-numbers-in-javascript#.Wm8rba6WYkI). Just find samples on the web, there's a lot out there, especially SO.

One more thing,

> **MAKE SURE YOUR SERIES AND LABELS ARE OF THE SAME LENGTH.**

You might need to check for `c_labels[i] !== null || c_labels[i] !== undefined`.

Comment: Hello, I've tried to convert your code to snippet but it has now some visual error :/

Comment: @RuslanLópez fixed. The series should be inside an array.